# Acumatica: Update Service Order from Appointment

Tags: acumatica

I need to customize the Appointment screen so that if a user selects the Billable Checkbox on the appointment, it will update the original service order. I was able to get this to work with a PXUpdate, but that didn't do any of the service order graph logic that updates document totals and taxes. I need to update the IsBillable checkbox on the service order but also have it run the ServiceOrderEntry events. I have the following code which runs through but doesn't update the service order. I'm at a loss. Any help is appreciated!

```
    protected void FSAppointmentDetPart_RowPersisted(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
    {
        var aptRow = e.Row as FSAppointmentDetPart;
        if (aptRow == null) return;

        var soGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ServiceOrderEntry>();

        FSSODet soDetRow = PXSelect<FSSODet, Where<FSSODet.sODetID, Equal<Required<FSSODet.sODetID>>>>.Select(soGraph, aptRow.SODetID);
        if (soDetRow == null) return;
        soGraph.Caches<FSSODet>().Current = soDetRow;

        FSServiceOrder serviceOrderRow = soGraph.ServiceOrderRecords.Current = soGraph.ServiceOrderRecords
                    .Search<FSServiceOrder.refNbr>(soDetRow.RefNbr, soDetRow.SrvOrdType);
        if (serviceOrderRow == null) return;

        if (soDetRow is FSSODetPart)
        {
            if (e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Delete)
            {
                soGraph.ServiceOrderDetParts.Delete(soDetRow as FSSODetPart);
            }
            else if (e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Update)
            {
                bool? isBillable = aptRow.IsBillable;
                soDetRow.IsBillable = aptRow.IsBillable;
                soGraph.Caches<FSSODet>().SetValueExt<FSSODet.isBillable>(soGraph, isBillable);

                decimal? estimatedQty = aptRow.EstimatedQty;
                soDetRow.EstimatedQty = aptRow.EstimatedQty;
                soGraph.Caches<FSSODet>().SetValueExt<FSSODet.estimatedQty>(soGraph, estimatedQty);

                soGraph.ServiceOrderDetParts.Cache.Update(soDetRow);
                soGraph.ServiceOrderRecords.Cache.Update(serviceOrderRow);

                soGraph.Actions.PressSave();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using soGraph.ServiceOrderRecords.Cache.RaiseFieldUpdated(soDetRow, null);